# How to use makefile with OpenBSD 5.8

Tags: c, makefile, openbsd

When I type make nothing happens. If I do it with Linux Ubuntu then make builds my projects. Why won't it work with BSD? The makefile is:

```
##################################################
## General configuration
## =====================

# Every Makefile should contain this line:
SHELL=/bin/sh

# Program for compiling C programs. 
CC=gcc

# What allocation strategy to use, and number of quick fit lists.
STRATEGY=4
NRQUICKLISTS=6

# Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it (the C and Fortran compilers). 
CFLAGS=-DSTRATEGY=$(STRATEGY) -DNRQUICKLISTS=$(NRQUICKLISTS)

# Default plus extra flags for C preprocessor and compiler.
all_cflags=$(CFLAGS) -Wall -Wextra -ansi -O4

# Malloc source file to use. Set to empty (with `make MALLOC=`) for system default.
MALLOC=malloc.c


##################################################
## Setup files variables
## =====================

# Source files to compile and link together
srcs=$(MALLOC) tstalgorithms.c tstcrash.c tstcrash_complex.c tstcrash_simple.c \
     tstextreme.c tstmalloc.c tstmemory.c tstmerge.c tstrealloc.c \
     tstbestcase.c tstworstcase.c

# Executables
execs=$(patsubst tst%.c, tst%, $(filter tst%.c, $(srcs)))


##################################################
## Ordinary targets
## ================

# http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets
# These are not the name of files that will be created by their recipes.
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(execs)

tst%: tst%.o $(MALLOC:.c=.o)
    $(CC) $(all_cflags) -o $@ $^

# These programs can not be compiled as ANSI-standard C.
tst%.o: tst%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# But the rest should be ANSI-standard C.
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(all_cflags) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o core $(execs)
```

This is the session:

```
$ strings `which make` | grep -B1 MAKE_VERSION
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
$ make -V MAKE_VERSION

$ make
$ ls
Makefile                                tstbestcase_time.gnuplot
README                                  tstcommon.h
README.md                               tstcrash.c
RUN_TESTS                               tstcrash_complex.c
a.out                                   tstcrash_simple.c
best.c                                  tstextreme.c
brk.h                                   tstmalloc.c
first.c                                 tstmemory.c
malloc.c                                tstmerge.c
malloc.h                                tstrealloc.c
quick.c                                 tstworstcase.c
tst.h                                   tstworstcase.dat.tgz
tstalgorithms.c                         tstworstcase_memory.gnuplot
tstbestcase.c                           tstworstcase_time.gnuplot
tstbestcase.dat.tgz                     worst.c
tstbestcase_memory.gnuplot
$
```

If I type `make malloc` then I get this output which I don't understand:

```
$ make malloc
gcc -DSTRATEGY=4 -DNRQUICKLISTS=6   -o malloc malloc.c 
/usr/lib/crt0.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error 1 in /home/niklas/malloc-master (<sys.mk>:85 'malloc')
$
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Something has to happen. Do you get an error? Do you get any output at all? Do you get to the next prompt? Does the shell hang? Is the name of that file `Makefile`? What version of `make` are you using?

Comment: I use `/usr/bin/make` from OpenBSD 5.8. It doesn't hang, it presents a new prompt without the compiler output. The Makefile works with Ubuntu.

Comment: That is surprising. What's the return code from running make? (i.e. What does `make; echo "$?"` output?) That being said that appears to be a GNU make makefile and openbsd's default make is most definitely **not** GNU make so that likely isn't going to work.

Comment: Return code 0 when running `make; echo "$?"`

Comment: Does `make -f Makefile` do anything different? Does `gmake` work?

Comment: return code 0 from running `make -f Makefile; echo "$?"`. The system doesn't have gmake.

Comment: I cannot understand what BSD make is doing there. I would have expected an error or something. This is truly puzzling. That being said either install GNU make/gmake or rewrite the makefile for BSD make and it should work.

Comment: It seems to start if I type `make malloc` then it starts compiling but it generates an error msg that I can't understand. I updated the question with this error msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `GNUmakefile`. `pkg_add gmake` and then type `gmake`, or, rewrite the `Makefile` to work under `make`.